# Auto downloading Salesforce weekly export files

Tags: data-export

We are looking for a way to auto download our Salesforce weekly export files to an internal server for long term storage.

Has anyone successfully done this either custom, using a 3rd party tool or tools (or some combination of both)?

Comment: Do you want to download data (ie: actual account and contact records) or metadata? (custom fields, validation rules, etc?)

Comment: This is for data downloads, the ones that Salesforce provides from the Setup > Data Management > Data Export. When you schedule them, you receive an email notification upon completion and have to log in to Production to access the link to download the compressed backup files.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Data Loader (You can easily schedule it for weekly run and save the data where you want). I've implemented this for one of my project.

Answer (score 1):

We make a [free tool](http://fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-Data-Exports.aspx) at FuseIT that can download the weekly data export and save it off disk for you. If you use the command line version then you can combine it with a scheduled task in Windows to automate the process.

Comment: So, this is a windows only?

Comment: @OK999, yes - unless you have a way to run a .NET based console application.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jitterbit allows that kind of functionality. You should definately check that one out!

http://www.jitterbit.com/

Comment: I'd be surprised if Jitterbit does make it possible since as far as I know the data export is not accessible through any API. While you could conceivably use Jitterbit to copy all your data, it is probably not the most efficient way to get the compressed data files that Salesforce provides.